# Pass global variable return null value. first page with modal page then to second page

Tags: php, mysql

I have search box `$_POST['search']` on the first page with modal page. On the modal page i was able to display the value from that search box. But when I click the submit button to post on the second page the search box variable return an empty value. pls help me on this.

**heres my html code**

```
<?php

session_start();

$globalpid = $_POST['search'];

$_SESSION['search'] = "$globalpid";

?>

<?php

require_once 'config.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello World">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
    <body>

        <div class="contaner">

            <header>

                <?php require_once 'header.php'; ?>

            </header>

                <?php require_once 'menu.php'; ?>
<div class="container">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Billing Section</h3></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form action="table.php" method="POST"  class="form-inline">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="search" size="50"  id="element-1" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 5px;" placeholder="Enter Patient ID" /><br />
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" style=" margin-top: 5px; width: 150px;" class="btn btn-info" />
                                    </div>  
                                </form>     
                            </div>

                            <?php

                                if (empty($_POST['search']))
                                {
                            ?>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                            <?php       echo "There was no search results!"; } ?>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your form action="url of first page". I think you are not assigning the $_POST['search'] to $globalpid. Try this code in first page:

first page

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $globalpid = $_POST['search'];
   $_SESSION['search'] = "$globalpid";
 }
 ?>
```

second page

```
<?php
  session_start();
  //print_r($_SESSION);
  if(isset($_SESSION['search'])){
      $globalpid = $_SESSION['search'];
      echo $globalpid;
  }
```

?>

Comment: thnx it work, iv been working for several days thx a lot. but theres an error 'undefined index: search...' when i added this $globalpid = $_POST['search'];?

Comment: Can you please add the html form source?

Comment: undefined index still exist

Comment: What is the name of you first page? I meant, the file name.

Comment: i named the first page is table.php

Comment: the undefined index exist when I load the table.php page

Comment: i have that already, the error is on the first page (table.php)

Comment: try changing the first page as the above.

Comment: when I added this $globalpid = $_POST['search']; in the session start on the first page, i can now pass the variable to the next but there's an error of undefined index: search...?

Comment: tried adding  if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $globalpid = $_POST['search'];
   $_SESSION['search'] = "$globalpid";
 }

?

Comment: On which line you are getting the error? Is it from an included file? Please send paste the error message.

Comment: if($_POST['search']){ --> "Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\table.php on line 5." Without the if statement the error message is the same pointing this--> $globalpid = $_POST['search'];

Comment: Great! please don't forget to accept the answer if it solves the issue. ;)